# What is different between Backend vs Frontend Cache of Magento

Tags: magento, caching

I use Magento Cache but I do not understand why Magento use Frontend and Backend cache.
I don't know why backend is set inside frontend,
and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Very layman concept: Front cache is a class that calls backend classes to implement cache types that you have setup in magento like  APC, Memcache or File System. So if you are using Memecache  , so those zend classes will be called by Frontend object to implement Memecache.